# The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it, even when using the dispatcher

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, thread-safety, dispatcher

I have a `Paragraph` object that I try to access from a different thread than it was created on, before posting my question here I searched for a solution online and I found the "Dispatcher" solution, which did not work for me, somehow.

Here's the code:

```
Run r = new Run((string)name + Environment.NewLine);
r.Foreground = Brushes.Green;
Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { currentlyOnlineParagraph.Inlines.Add(r); }), DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle);
```

I get this error:

> ```
> InvalidOperationException was unhandled
> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
> Additional information: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.
> ```

[image: screenshot]

How can I address this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the few lines of code I see,I would try to create all graphical objects on the graphical thread, including the `Run` object:

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => {   
   Run r = new Run((string)name + Environment.NewLine);
   r.Foreground = Brushes.Green;
   currentlyOnlineParagraph.Inlines.Add(r);   
}), DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle);
```